# Set a limit to upload box onClick jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to add a simple upload box, however, I want to limit the number of uploads onClick of + . How can I add this to the addFile function? I know I need to add a counter of sorts and put the query in an if loop to deny access if the + button is clicked more than 5 times. But how do I do this in jquery?

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <table class="adminformlist" id="uploading">
        <tr><td align="left">Upload Images(Maximum of 5 images):
            <input type="hidden" size="40" class="inputbox" value="" id="getyoutube" name="youtubevalue">
            <input type="hidden" size="40" class="inputbox" value="" id="getyoutubeurl" name="youtubevalueurl">
            </td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>   
        <tr><td><input type="file" name="images[]"></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="button" onclick="return addFile(this)">+</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function addFile(el){
        jQuery(el).parent().append('<a href="#" class="button" onclick="return removeFile(this)">x</a>');
        jQuery(el).remove();
        jQuery("#uploading").append('<tr><td><input type="file" name="images[]"></td><td><a href="#" class="button" onclick="return addFile(this)">+</a></td></tr>');
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function addFile(el){
  var allowedNumberofTR = 6;
  if($('#uploading tr').length < allowedNumberofTR){
      //your code
  }
}
```

Remind you, since `uploading` div already has a tr, `allowedNumberofTR` should always be +1. Change the allowed tr to a value you need and try it out.

```js
function addFile(el){
        if($("#uploading tr").length < 6){
        jQuery(el).parent().append('<a href="#" class="button" onclick="return removeFile(this)">x</a>');
        jQuery(el).remove();
        jQuery("#uploading").append('<tr><td><input type="file" name="images[]"></td><td><a href="#" class="button" onclick="return addFile(this)">+</a></td></tr>');
        return false;
          }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <table class="adminformlist" id="uploading">
        <tr><td align="left">Upload Images(Maximum of 5 images):
            <input type="hidden" size="40" class="inputbox" value="" id="getyoutube" name="youtubevalue">
            <input type="hidden" size="40" class="inputbox" value="" id="getyoutubeurl" name="youtubevalueurl">
            </td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>   
        <tr><td><input type="file" name="images[]"></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="button" onclick="return addFile(this)">+</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: It worked perfect, just as I wanted it. Thank you so much. Can I also add to the function, so that when the X button is clicked to cancel/close an upload box, the entire upload box is closed? At the moment when I click on X, only the X button disappears, the upload box itself still remains. Thank You

Comment: yes you can, If I got you right.. this should work...  add `jQuery(el).closest('tr').remove();` instead of `jQuery(el).remove();`. This selects the closest `tr` and removes it :)

Comment: I tried the code, but now it has disabled the + append button. onClick, nothing happens; it doesn't append new upload boxes

Comment: Can you post other question so that I can have a look at it. I think there is something that is blocking your script execution.

Answer (score 0):

at the begining of your addFile function add following code

```
if($('input[type="file"]').length==5){
    return false;
}
```